# Primefaces autocomplete rows appearing above <p:autoComplete

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have primefaces `autocomplete` which is fetching values from database.
When I type in characters, I could see rows in `autocomplete` are sometimes appearing above 
`<p:autoComplete`, it should appear normally below `<p:autoComplete`.

See below screenshot for reference. How can I resolve this issue?

Primesfaces version 3.1

JSF code

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.selectedEmployees}"  
 completeMethod="#{bean.employeeList}"  
        var="vs" itemLabel="#{vs.empName}" itemValue="#{vs.empName}"  multiple="true"> 

        <p:column style="width:100%;text-align:center">  
            #{vs.empName} - #{vs.empNumber}  
        </p:column>  
    </p:autoComplete>
```

Regards

[image]

*Update 1*

ManagedBean

```
public List<Schedules> employeeList(String query) {

for(Schedules vs : employees) {  
                if(vs.getEmpName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))  
                    suggestions.add(vs);    
            }
return suggestions;
```

and in constructor

```
employees = MyDAO.loadEmployees();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I believe the reason is when you have a large suggestion list, primefaces sees it can't fit within the browser boundary if it was displayed downwards, so it just blindly flip the dropdown upwards. (which possibly makes it worse) Try add scrollHeight to limit the dropdown length although I heard scrollHeight also has its own problem

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the issue with scrollHeight ?

Answer (score 0):

It was reported as bug and fixed in 3.1 [Autocomplete is displaced above input when initial results are restricted while typing](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3256)

**Try cleaning your cache...**

*Update 1*

To be on the safe side:
Make sure that employees is never null, and move its init into a `@PostConstruct` method...

Comment: I have cleaned my cache, still problem persists. Importantly I have noticed that this happens not for all, only for few where I type in characters like moh and results from database shows 600 in my bean whereas in jsf it displays only one row and that too above the inputfield like in the screenshot.

Comment: do you see anything in the console log of the browser (firebug)?

Comment: I could see records in firebug console, but not in autocomplete, only one records gets displayed on top of inputfield. No errors in firebug console.

Comment: with smaller data set the autocmplete renders properly?

Comment: Yes for smaller set of data autocomplete renders correctly. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: well.. if it renders well for a small data set , it should render the same for a bigger data set as well... looks like a bug to me...

Comment: To rule out any issues with my bean. I have added above my code as update 1. Thanks

Comment: I tried your updated solution as well, but same issues persists. Thanks

Comment: I tried moving down <p:autoComplete to have more space, then I could more drop down rows. However those rows appear on top :-(

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `maxResults` property to 10 or

example:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{backingBean.value}" maxResults="10" />
```

this will solve your problem.