# <p:autoComplete> renders dropdownlist to top when the list is too large

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:autoComplete>` in my webproject. When lots of data coming to the search box the position of list is from bottom to top instead of top to bottom and not all data is visible.

[image: PF **AutoComplete** issue]

How can I fix it so that it shows the data from top to bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the scrollHeight attribute to define height of the items those are seen in list as follows

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.text}" completeMethod="#{bean.complete}" scrollHeight = "150" />
```

Primefaces documentation will definitely help you regarding this

Comment: Thanks but as i saw this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710099/primefaces-autocomplete-rows-appearing-above-pautocomplete they mentioned its have also some isue

Comment: I am using primefaces 3.5. I couldn't face this issue so tried to answer it as to my ability :)

Comment: One more think you know ..Can you tell me how can onselect any item from autoselect we can call a method?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p:autoComplete id="acOrden" value="#{serviciosMB.ordenSelect}"
                                            completeMethod="#{serviciosMB.complete}"
                                            var="mauto"   
                                            itemValue="#{mauto}" 
                                            itemLabel="#{mauto.consecutivoOrden}"
                                            converter="ordenProduccionServiciolConverter" required="true">
                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{serviciosMB.renderPanelOrden}" update="panelOrden :form2:growl" />
                                <p:column>
                                    #{mauto.codigoOrden}
                                </p:column>
                            </p:autoComplete>
```

see ajax listener

Comment: What you want to say here i did not get you?